# Update Trigger Instead of Delete is not working

Tags: mysql, view, triggers, sql-delete

so i have assigned when i deleted a row, it will be update to 0.

this is my view

```
IF object_id ('dbo.transaction', 'v') IS NOT NULL
DROP VIEW dbo.transaction;

GO
CREATE VIEW transaction
as 
SELECT SUM(OD.UnitPrice*OD.Quantity) AS total, MONTH(O.OrderDate) AS month, YEAR(O.OrderDate) As year
FROM Orders O
JOIN [Order Details] OD
ON O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
GROUP BY MONTH(O.OrderDate), YEAR(O.OrderDate)
go
```

then i used a trigger that when i deleted a month or year it will change to 0

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsteadOfDelete
ON transaction
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
update transaction
set total = 0, month = 0, year = 0
go
```

the trigger is successfully added but when i tried to delete a month or year in my view it's got error.

```
delete from transaction
where month = 6
```

is there any problem with my trigger?

Comment: Your code is not MySQL-related, this is SQL Server aka MS SQL syntax. Re-tag the question.

Comment: *when i tried to delete a month or year in my view it's got error.* I doubt that the view which includes GROUP BY may be updatable even in theory.. moreover, I don't understand what should be deleted in base tables when you try to delete from this view..